# sqlite encryption in windows phone 8.1

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

i am developing apps for windows phone 8.1 using visual studio 2014 update 4 i am also using sqlite database from nuget source to store data.I want to password encrypt my database file, i got libraries such as open ssl and sqlenrypt but they are paid which i cannot afford.can anyone help me out with free library.
I have also checked out with sqlcipher(one of the open source library) but i didnt got any points to merge it with my project.if other libraries are also there than please provide me with steps to integrate with project.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Windows Cryptography Encryption technique to encrypt and decrypt files.

**For Encryption:**

```
private async Task<string> EncryptFileHelper(string source, string destination)
    {
        StorageFolder appFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                try
                {
                    StorageFile file = await appFolder.GetFileAsync(source);
                    IBuffer fileStreamBuffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
                    string protectionDescriptor = "LOCAL=user";
                    Windows.Security.Cryptography.DataProtection.DataProtectionProvider provider = String.IsNullOrEmpty(protectionDescriptor) ? new Windows.Security.Cryptography.DataProtection.DataProtectionProvider() : new Windows.Security.Cryptography.DataProtection.DataProtectionProvider(protectionDescriptor);
                    IBuffer encryptedBuffer = await provider.ProtectAsync(fileStreamBuffer);

                    StorageFile encryptedFile = await appFolder.CreateFileAsync(destination, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                    await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(encryptedFile, encryptedBuffer);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return "fail";
                }
            return "success";
    }
```

In **source**, just pass the path of your file you want to encrypt and In **destination**, pass your path you want to store your encrypted file. destination may be the same path. Like:

```
string source = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "\\YourFolder\\YourFileName.sqlite";
```

**For Decryption:**

```
private async Task<string> DecryptFileHelper(string source, string destination)
    {
        StorageFolder appFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
         try
                {
                    StorageFile file = await appFolder.GetFileAsync(source);
                    IBuffer fileStreamBuffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);
                    string protectionDescriptor = "LOCAL=user";
                    Windows.Security.Cryptography.DataProtection.DataProtectionProvider provider = String.IsNullOrEmpty(protectionDescriptor) ? new Windows.Security.Cryptography.DataProtection.DataProtectionProvider() : new Windows.Security.Cryptography.DataProtection.DataProtectionProvider(protectionDescriptor);
                    IBuffer encryptedBuffer = await provider.UnprotectAsync(fileStreamBuffer);

                    StorageFile encryptedFile = await appFolder.CreateFileAsync(destination, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                    await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(encryptedFile, encryptedBuffer);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return "fail";
                }
            return "success";
    }
```

Hope it helps! Thanks!

Comment: thanks MR. but for each query i will need to encrypt and decrypt the database file which will reduce the performance.I want something like the database should only be accessible by using password.

Comment: Oh I thought you just need to encrypt sqlite file. Yes encrypting and decrypting file every time will reduce performance.

Comment: and also if the file is above 40 mb then it throws exception of insufficient memory available.(512 mb of RAM).